# Page Refresh Problem in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I have a html like below.Here inside the content div we are openning a html page targetPage.html on click of next.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
* {margin:0;padding:0}
body {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 1em;
    background: #bef2a5;
}

h2 {color: white;}
#side {background: #7c8f50;}
#main {background: #426142;}
html {overflow: hidden;}
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;    
    left: 0px;
    width:100%;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #339933;
}
#main {
    position: absolute;    
    top: 100px;
    left: 240px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#side {    
    position: absolute;    
    top: 100px;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;    
}
h2,p {padding:10px;margin:0 0 .5em 0}

iframe{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadPageTarget(url, containerid) {
    var page_request = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    page_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
            try {
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch(e) {}
        }
    } else
        return false;
        page_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        loadpage(page_request, containerid);
        }
    page_request.open('GET', url, true)
        page_request.send(null);
    }

function loadpage(page_request, containerid) {
    if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status == 200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1))
          document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML = page_request.responseText;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<input type="button" value="Next" onClick="javascript:loadPageTarget('targetPage.html','content');"/>
</div>
<div id="side">
</div>
<div id="main">
    <div class="content" id="content">
        <iframe name="myFrame" frameborder="0" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe> 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The page targetPage look like below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<iframe id ="test" src="test.html/>" style="width: 1130px; height: 601px;" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0">
</iframe>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Now after opening the targetPage if I press the refresh button on safari then the page is going back to google.com but on mozilla its coming back to the test.html page inside content.Any idea about how to make it work in Safari ?

Answer (score 1):

This part of your html is not correct:

```
<iframe id ="test" src="test.html/>" style="width: 1130px; height: 601px;" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0">
</iframe>
```

should be

```
<iframe id ="test" src="test.html" style="width: 1130px; height: 601px;" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0">
</iframe>
```

you had errors with the double quotes so it was not rendering correctly

**UPDATE:**

here is another thing you need to change:

```
<input type="button" value="Next" onClick="javascript:loadPageTarget('targetPage.html','content');"/>
```

should be:

```
<input type="button" value="Next" onClick="loadPageTarget('targetPage.html','content');"/>
```

Comment: Thnx for the reply but I made typos over there even after correcting it is not workin...